# Using Photoshop with monitor color calibrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors

I have a SpyderPro 4 monitor color calibrator I use to calibrate the displays on my Windows 10 system. I use Photoshop CC for design work and photo editing. I never do any work for print, just for software and web use. Please note I have two monitors and they use different calibration profiles in the Spyder software.

I've noticed that the colors I see outside of Photoshop are different than the colors I see in Photoshop. For example, if I take a screenshot and paste it into Photoshop, the colors appear slightly different. Or if I save an image as a JPG or PNG and open that image with a photo viewer, it looks a little different than Photoshop. I'm sure this has to do with the default color profile in Photoshop, but I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to configure the color profile. Right now these are my color settings in Photoshop: [image: Color Settings]

I've read Adobe's documentation from [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WSBB0A8512-8151-408c-9F79-4A9E9E3BA84C.html) but I feel like some steps are missing. After I calibrate my monitor with the SpyderPro, am I supposed to load the color profile generated by the Spyder into Photoshop? What would I do if the calibrated profiles on each of my monitors are different? When I open a PSD created on another computer, do I want to preserve the embedded color profile or convert it to my working space?

Comment: Oh cool I never knew there was such a thing! Checking out that calibrator now :)

Comment: update: oh, it is hardware. And $150.

Comment: You can't accurately calibrate a monitor without hardware. I think I got mine on sale for around $100. If you do any professional design work or photo editing, a color calibrator is a must-have